# is there any way to customise a control style in iOS using material visual?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.entry

I'm trying to customise an `Entry` field for iOS platform with `Visual=Material` enabled.

I tried via `CustomRenderer` but since is iOS platform I don't know to how to reach, for example, to modify the material bottom border color without modifying the whole text color for the control.

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(CustomMaterialEntryRenderer), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]

    public class CustomMaterialEntryRenderer : MaterialEntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null) return;

            Layer.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#cedee7").ToCGColor();
        }
    }
```

To be clear enough, just in case, I want the bottom line for example in red and text in black.

[image: Entry Example]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect that you might have to create your own custom control and style it accordingly.. Have a look here though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/styling?pivots=windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems an existing issue that the `CustomRenderer` will never been called .We will focus on this issue .

#### Workaround 1:

If you just want to set the underline color of `Entry` . It is unnecessary to set `Visual=Material`.You just need to create a default **Custom Renderer** of `Entry`.

```
if (Control != null)
{

  Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
 
  UIView lineView = new UIView()
  {

     Frame = new CGRect(0, Element.HeightRequest - 1, Element.WidthRequest, 1),
     BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red,

  };
 
  Control.AddSubview(lineView);
 
}
```

Don't forget to set the `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` in xaml.

#### Workaround 2

Fortunately,there are many plugin of Material Controls from nuget. And you can download and use it directly . For example [MaterialFormControls](https://github.com/fpt-software/Material-Controls-For-iOS)

Download the package from Nuget Manager (make sure to check the include prerelease)
[image]

And set the property AccentColor to change the under line color

```
<local:MaterialEntry IsPassword="True" Placeholder="email" AccentColor="Red"/>
```

Comment: I decided to use the Nuget from Suave Pirate and it works perfectly; hope this issue is fixed soon, I think it's a cool feature without use third-parties Nuget. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I have posted it to github and we will focus on it.